# Can you remove the css class prefix in React (Modular css)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sass

I'm using React & NextJS and I've noticed that when using modular scss files, it's autoprefixing my classnames with the name of the file?

Is there a way to disable this? As it makes the DOM quite difficult to read.

E.G. in my code below the div class is ***"splash_splashContent_3R9Lp"*** when I would prefer it to be **"splashContent_3R9Lp"** and not be prefixed with the scss filename.

Is this possible?

**File structure**

```
Components
 - Splash
   - Splash.jsx
   - splash.module.scss
```

**JSX:**

```
import React from "react"
import styles from './splash.module.scss'

export const Splash = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.splashContent}>
      <p>Splash text goes here</p>
    </div>
  )
};
```

**SCSS**

```
.splashContent {
 example code goes here
}
```

**DOM**

```
<div class="splash_splashContent_3R9Lp>
 <p>Splash text goes here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try to install this dependencies :

```
npm install @zeit/next-sass sass
```

and then update your nex.config.js:

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

module.exports = withSass({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    modules: {
      getLocalIdent: (_, localIdentName, localName) => localName,
    },
  },
});
```